# JAX-RS interceptor cannot work

Tags: java, jax-rs, interceptor

I wanted to use a interceptor(custom annotation) inside a jax-rs service.

1.First,I wrote an annotation class:
BasicAuthentication.java:

```
@NameBinding
@Target( {ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BasicAuthentication {
}
```

2.Then I added the BasicAuthenticationInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.ext.ReaderInterceptor

BasicAuthenticationInterceptor.java:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
@BasicAuthentication

public class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor extends Dumpable implements ReaderInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Object aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorContext context) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        //log.info("authentication here")
        String authHeader = context.getHeaders().getFirst(AUTHORIZATION);
        if (authHeader == null) {
            error("\"authorization\" is not found from the request header.");
            throw new WebApplicationException(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
        return  context.proceed();
    }
}
```

3.At last,I add a test service with annotation @BasicAuthentication.

TestRestfulService.java

```
@Stateless
@Path("/api")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@BasicAuthentication
public class TestRestfulService extends Dumpable{
@EJB
LocalService localService;

@Path("/test/{id}")
@GET
public Response test(@PathParam("id")String id) {
try {
    localService.findUser(id);
} catch (Exception e) {
    error(e);
    return Response.serverError().build();
}
return Response.ok().build();
}
}
```

But every time I request /api/test/1 with empty header,I can get the correct response,the interceptor seems not work at all.

I'm using Wildfly 10.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked out.Change the Interceptor to filter:

```
public class BasicAuthenticationInterceptor implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context){
        ...
    }
}
```

Then it works as expected.

Form JAX-WS API:

> Interface for message body reader interceptors that wrap around calls to MessageBodyReader.readFrom(java.lang.Class, java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.annotation.Annotation[], javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType, javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap, java.io.InputStream).

[javax.ws.rs.ReaderInterceptor](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/ReaderInterceptor.html)

This could be the reason.